# Danger when using catfile for a path ending in a directory?

Tags: perl, directory-structure

The [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) module provides a way to create cross-OS valid paths. It works as one would expect:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my $file = 'ghi.xml';
my $path = File::Spec->catfile(('abc', 'def'), $file);
print $path;
# Windows: abc/def/ghi.xml
```

A method `catdir` is also available, which would result in a directory - not a path to a file.

My issue is that I do not know in advance if `$file` is a file name or a directory name. As far as I have tested, the results are still correct when using a dirname instead, e.g.:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my $file = 'ghi';
my $path = File::Spec->catfile(('abc', 'def'), $file);
print $path;
# Windows: abc/def/ghi
```

But I wonder whether this can cause issues anyway. I am assuming *yes* because I don't understand why the creators of the module would build two interfaces for the same functionality. However, I cannot find any further explanation in the documentation.

Is it safe to use `catfile` to create paths to files as well as to directories? If not, what are the caveats?

Comment: [code](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/PathTools-3.62/lib/File/Spec/Win32.pm#L130-162) looks the same to me, except that early return for catdir.

Comment: @salparadise You're looking at `File::Spec::Win32`, and the OP hasn't said what platform they're using.

Comment: How can you not know whether you're dealing with a file or a directory?

Comment: @Borodin When doing a readdir, for instance. to check `-d` I need the full path (i.e. concatenate the read item with the read dir), so I don't know in advance what they are. (This is just an example, not my actual case.)

Comment: This probably makes a difference on VMS and other "exotic" systems. If you're only dealing with Unix-ish systems and Windows, you can just use `'abc/def/ghi'` and be done with it.

Comment: @borodin sure, he did have a comment on his example of using Windows, hence the link, it wasn't meant as an answer, just a pointer to actual source code.

Comment: @BramVanroy: The answer to that would be to `chdir` to the directory you are reading and test the bare node name, letting the system work out the full path. What is your acual case?

Comment: @salparadise: Oh I didn't see that. It doesn't exactly stand out! But I think that relying on the quirks of a particular platform rather spoils the point of `File::Spec`.

Comment: @melpomene Internally, yes. But if anything outside your program is going to see it, it must be in canonical form to avoid problems.

Comment: It matters with native VMS paths. I think they look like `[DIR]FILE;VERSION`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference of the `catdir` and `catfile` is usually very small (**depends on the used OS**). On the UNIX, the `catfile` does `catdir` anyway for the *directory* elements (e.g. minus the last (file) part) and then appends the *file* part. The `catdir` does some path-cleaning logic. On the windows platform the differences even less.

You can check the [source of the module(s) for the different OS-es](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/PathTools-3.62/lib/File/Spec) yourself.

The main thing is: these routines doesn't do any filesystem access, just doing some logical path cleaning.

---

**Alternative:**

If you don't care about the other OS-es as UNIX-like (e.g. Linux, FreeBSD, Mac OS X etc..) **and** Windows, me personally recommending to use the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module. From it's doc:

> This module provides a small, fast utility for working with file
>   paths. It is friendlier to use than File::Spec and provides easy
>   access to functions from several other core file handling modules. It
>   aims to be smaller and faster than many alternatives on CPAN, while
>   helping people do many common things in consistent and less
>   error-prone ways.
>
> Path::Tiny does not try to work for anything except Unix-like and
>   Win32 platforms.

IMHO - it is one of the best modules on CPAN - real treasure. For example, for the path creation you should use the `child` method - again from the docs:

> ```
> $file = path("/tmp")->child("foo.txt"); # "/tmp/foo.txt"
> $file = path("/tmp")->child(@parts);
> ```
>
> Returns a new Path::Tiny object relative to the original. Works like
>   `catfile` or `catdir` from File::Spec, but without caring about file
>   or directories.

Except the above the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module provides easy access to file contents, (also with unicode handling) and every commonly needed "path" operations. Drawback: unfortunately, it isn't CORE module, e.g. you need install it from the CPAN.

#### EDIT

Is safe to use `catfile` for the directories? By me: *yes* (but maybe some experts will know something else or more). On unix,

- the `catdir` calls the `canonpath` (which does some logical path-cleaning).
- the `catfile` calls the `canonpath` twice, once for the *file* part and once for the *directories* (if they are provided),  and concatenate the two results. The concatenation could result some strange looking paths, but they're generally harmless.

On Windows, the differences even less, both will call the path-cleaning routine.

Demo - the following script will generate many combinations of different parts and will use the `catdir` and `catfile` (and even two variants of the `Path::Tiny`)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions;
use Path::Tiny;

my @parts = qw(x / /x /x/ /x// // //x //x/ //x// /./ /./x /x/./ );
my $cwidth=16;
print pr(qw(first second catdir catfile path-child path-list)), "\n";
print '-' x ($cwidth*6),"\n";
for my $first (map { s/x/first/r } @parts) {
    for my $second ( map { s/x/second/r } @parts) {
        print pr(
            $first,
            $second,
            catdir($first,$second),
            catfile($first,$second),
            path($first)->child($second),
            path($first,$second),
        ), "\n";
    }
}
sub pr {
    my $str;
    $str .= sprintf "%-${cwidth}s",$_ for @_;
    return $str;
}
```

It prints an long result. As you can see bellow the all paths are safe for use for directories and files, just some paths from the `catfile` isn't "nice".

The both "Path::Tiny" results are clear and consistent. Contrary, the `catfile` and `catdir` will allow to use undefined parts, (not shown in the demo) - and even in such errornous arguments *will produce some results*, the Path::Tiny *will die* if you pass undef or null-string to its `child` method.

```
first           second          catdir          catfile         path-child      path-list       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
first           second          first/second    first/second    first/second    first/second    
first           /               first           first//         first           first           
first           /second         first/second    first//second   first/second    first/second    
first           /second/        first/second    first//second   first/second    first/second    
first           /second//       first/second    first//second   first/second    first/second    
first           //              first           first//         first           first           
first           //second        first/second    first//second   first/second    first/second    
first           //second/       first/second    first//second   first/second    first/second    
first           //second//      first/second    first//second   first/second    first/second    
first           /./             first           first//         first           first           
first           /./second       first/second    first//second   first/second    first/second    
first           /second/./      first/second    first//second   first/second    first/second    
/               second          /second         /second         /second         /second         
/               /               /               //              /               /               
/               /second         /second         //second        /second         /second         
/               /second/        /second         //second        /second         /second         
/               /second//       /second         //second        /second         /second         
/               //              /               //              /               /               
/               //second        /second         //second        /second         /second         
/               //second/       /second         //second        /second         /second         
/               //second//      /second         //second        /second         /second         
/               /./             /               //              /               /               
/               /./second       /second         //second        /second         /second         
/               /second/./      /second         //second        /second         /second         
/first          second          /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   
/first          /               /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first          /second         /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first          /second/        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first          /second//       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first          //              /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first          //second        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first          //second/       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first          //second//      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first          /./             /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first          /./second       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first          /second/./      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/         second          /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   
/first/         /               /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first/         /second         /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/         /second/        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/         /second//       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/         //              /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first/         //second        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/         //second/       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/         //second//      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/         /./             /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first/         /./second       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/         /second/./      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first//        second          /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   
/first//        /               /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first//        /second         /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first//        /second/        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first//        /second//       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first//        //              /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first//        //second        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first//        //second/       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first//        //second//      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first//        /./             /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first//        /./second       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first//        /second/./      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//              second          /second         /second         /second         /second         
//              /               /               //              /               /               
//              /second         /second         //second        /second         /second         
//              /second/        /second         //second        /second         /second         
//              /second//       /second         //second        /second         /second         
//              //              /               //              /               /               
//              //second        /second         //second        /second         /second         
//              //second/       /second         //second        /second         /second         
//              //second//      /second         //second        /second         /second         
//              /./             /               //              /               /               
//              /./second       /second         //second        /second         /second         
//              /second/./      /second         //second        /second         /second         
//first         second          /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   
//first         /               /first          /first//        /first          /first          
//first         /second         /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first         /second/        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first         /second//       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first         //              /first          /first//        /first          /first          
//first         //second        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first         //second/       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first         //second//      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first         /./             /first          /first//        /first          /first          
//first         /./second       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first         /second/./      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first/        second          /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   
//first/        /               /first          /first//        /first          /first          
//first/        /second         /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first/        /second/        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first/        /second//       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first/        //              /first          /first//        /first          /first          
//first/        //second        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first/        //second/       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first/        //second//      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first/        /./             /first          /first//        /first          /first          
//first/        /./second       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first/        /second/./      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first//       second          /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   
//first//       /               /first          /first//        /first          /first          
//first//       /second         /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first//       /second/        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first//       /second//       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first//       //              /first          /first//        /first          /first          
//first//       //second        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first//       //second/       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first//       //second//      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first//       /./             /first          /first//        /first          /first          
//first//       /./second       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
//first//       /second/./      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/./             second          /second         /second         /second         /second         
/./             /               /               //              /               /               
/./             /second         /second         //second        /second         /second         
/./             /second/        /second         //second        /second         /second         
/./             /second//       /second         //second        /second         /second         
/./             //              /               //              /               /               
/./             //second        /second         //second        /second         /second         
/./             //second/       /second         //second        /second         /second         
/./             //second//      /second         //second        /second         /second         
/./             /./             /               //              /               /               
/./             /./second       /second         //second        /second         /second         
/./             /second/./      /second         //second        /second         /second         
/./first        second          /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   
/./first        /               /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/./first        /second         /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/./first        /second/        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/./first        /second//       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/./first        //              /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/./first        //second        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/./first        //second/       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/./first        //second//      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/./first        /./             /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/./first        /./second       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/./first        /second/./      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/./       second          /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   /first/second   
/first/./       /               /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first/./       /second         /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/./       /second/        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/./       /second//       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/./       //              /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first/./       //second        /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/./       //second/       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/./       //second//      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/./       /./             /first          /first//        /first          /first          
/first/./       /./second       /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second   
/first/./       /second/./      /first/second   /first//second  /first/second   /first/second
```

Comment: So as Melpomene comments on the OP, I'd probably be safe when only concerning UNIX-based systems and Windows? Thanks for the link to Path::Tiny, I'll have a look at it. Any reason (except for the topic at hand) that it's better than the functionality in File::Spec?

Comment: @BramVanroy - imho, it is safe - but see the EDIT.